# DirectorySearcher working in Local but not working in IIS server

Tags: c#, iis, ldap, azure-active-directory, directorysearcher

I want to list the all mail list or search a mail id present in my Active directory so I have used the DirectorySearcher like following and working in my local system if I run it via visual studio but not working when I publish or deploy these code to an IIS server.

My C# Code,

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult getADEmail(string query = "")
{
    DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
    dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectcategory=person)(mail=" + query + "*))";

    SearchResult srEmail = dirSearcher.FindOne();
    SearchResultCollection SearchResultCollection = dirSearcher.FindAll();
    string propName = "mail";
    ResultPropertyValueCollection valColl = srEmail.Properties[propName];

    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    foreach (SearchResult sr in SearchResultCollection)
    {
        ResultPropertyValueCollection val = sr.Properties[propName];
        results.Add(val[0].ToString());
    }

    return Json(results);
}
```

Directory Path in my local,

```
"LDAP://DC=arcadis-nl,DC=local" from (dirSearcher.SearchRoot.Path)  
 The IIS is on another server: 154:139:1:150
```

Where I did go wrong?What should I do to resolve this issue?.

Comment: what user is is your code on the iis server running as, your local one is likely to be you

Comment: Typical misunderstanding of IIS, so hints are in https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: you could try to change in the application pool identity into the windows service account of the AD box.iis user does not have enough permission to access the ad.

Comment: @Jalpa, Where to change the permission? Can you send me a link to follow?

Comment: I have permission for the IIS server but still not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a directory permissions problem.Few things to check:

- Does the user (or machine) that is connecting to the IIS server have permissions to perform the query?

In these kind of scenario , we have to set the identity of the application pool to a user who has access to the directory.

Additional reference:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599697/Get-list-of-Active-Directory-users-in-Csharp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Permission means to what? I did not give any user names or passwords in my local code also. So I need to get access for the particular server or what?

Comment: By default , when you run in local it is considering your user a default one i assume..

Comment: Your application in IIS must be running under a identity which you have to change it

Comment: Is that windows user ? or Need to create an identity separately?

Comment: For a starter, try putting your user name under identity and see if it works. If it works , you can create a service account which would act as a proxy user to get all the email records.

Comment: I am new to IIS, so can you please tell me step by step to add my name in the identity?